# pintar tabla html con php segun condicion el if

Tags: php, html

este es mi codigo de php en la vista quiero que al recorrer este foreach al llegar al if evalue una condicion por pais si es tiene VE que muestre lo que esta en el ELSE si tiene EC-bp que muestre lo que esta en esa linea

```
foreach ($datos->lista as $value) {
array_push($tempidOrdenLotes, $value->idOrdenTemp);
$ltr="<tr class='OShead-2 OSinfo $value->idOrden'>
<td>".lang('TABLA_COS_NRO_LOTE')."</td>
<td>".lang('TABLA_COS_FECHA')."</td>
<td>".lang('TABLA_COS_TIPO')."</td>
<td>".lang('TABLA_COS_CANT')."</td>
<td>".lang('TABLA_COS_STATUS')."</td>";
if($pais=='Ec-bp'){
"<td>".lang('TABLA_COS_RECEPCION')."</td>";
}else{
"<td>".lang('TABLA_COS_MONTO_RECA')."</td>";
}
"<td>".lang('TABLA_COS_MONTO_COMI')."</td>
 <td>".lang('TABLA_COS_MONTO_TOTAL')."</td>
</tr>";
```

el mismo no me pinta lo tres ultima filas
o que estoy haciendo mal???

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres cuando dices que _no me pinta lo tres ultima filas_? ¿de qué filas hablas, si sólo muestras una fila? ¿Cuál es el resto de tu código? ¿Tienes una etiqueta `<table>` de apertura y la cierras adecuadamente?  ¿Qué arroja un `var_dump($pais);`

Answer (score 1):

Verifica que la variable $pais contenga valor, utiliza echo $pais para que veas que valor te imprime antes de pasar al pintar la tabla, checa que al momento de imprimir el valor de $pais sea igual al que lo estas comparando

```
foreach ($datos->lista as $value) {
echo $pais;
array_push($tempidOrdenLotes, $value->idOrdenTemp);
$ltr="<tr class='OShead-2 OSinfo $value->idOrden'>
<td>".lang('TABLA_COS_NRO_LOTE')."</td>
<td>".lang('TABLA_COS_FECHA')."</td>
<td>".lang('TABLA_COS_TIPO')."</td>
<td>".lang('TABLA_COS_CANT')."</td>
<td>".lang('TABLA_COS_STATUS')."</td>";
if($pais=='Ec-bp'){
"<td>".lang('TABLA_COS_RECEPCION')."</td>";
}else{
"<td>".lang('TABLA_COS_MONTO_RECA')."</td>";
}
"<td>".lang('TABLA_COS_MONTO_COMI')."</td>
 <td>".lang('TABLA_COS_MONTO_TOTAL')."</td>
</tr>";
}
```

Comment: si me llega la respuesta del pais

Comment: Las depuraciones hay que hacerlas con `var_dump`, no con `echo`. Por ejemplo, esto: `Ec-bp` y esto, `Ec-bp ` no es igual. Cuando haces `echo` no percibes una diferencia: el 2º tiene un espacio en blanco  y por tanto no validaría como igual al 1º. Con `var_dump` por la longitud sabrás que no son iguales.

Answer (score 0):

puedes usar `strpos` segun la documentación:

https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.strpos.php

Un ejemplo basico del uso:

```
$a = 'How are you?';
if (strpos($a, 'are') !== false) {
    echo 'true';
}
```

Un ejemplo con tu código:

```
foreach ($datos->lista as $value) {
    array_push($tempidOrdenLotes, $value->idOrdenTemp);
    $ltr="<tr class='OShead-2 OSinfo $value->idOrden'>
    <td>".lang('TABLA_COS_NRO_LOTE')."</td>
    <td>".lang('TABLA_COS_FECHA')."</td>
    <td>".lang('TABLA_COS_TIPO')."</td>
    <td>".lang('TABLA_COS_CANT')."</td>
    <td>".lang('TABLA_COS_STATUS')."</td>";
    if(strpos($pais, 'VE') !== false){ //uso VE como indicaste
        "<td>".lang('TABLA_COS_RECEPCION')."</td>";
    }else{
        "<td>".lang('TABLA_COS_MONTO_RECA')."</td>";
    }
    "<td>".lang('TABLA_COS_MONTO_COMI')."</td>
    <td>".lang('TABLA_COS_MONTO_TOTAL')."</td>
    </tr>";
}
```

Validara cualquier iteración del foreach que contenga las letras `VE`